# How to remove old generated pages (Next js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I would like to know if there is any way to delete old generated pages after revalidation(ISR) in Next.js. Suppose I am fetching data from a news api and generating static pages with latest data. But I don't want to keep the old generated news pages. Is there any way to do it instead of manually deleting it?

Comment: Did you find anything? I was looking for a solution for this problem on my end.

Comment: @KutsanKaplan, no I haven't found the answer yet.